# Python - Pandas manipulating data frames in loops

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I'm manipulating data with pandas and having some trouble when using for loops.

Basically, I'm dealing with some time series with prices, and I have to calculate the percentage change in daily prices; I only need to work with these values, and only for the last 750 days. Say I have three data frames, one for each product A, B, and C, which include only date and daily price. I've written this:

```
import pandas as pd

products= [A, B, C]

for df in products:
    df["change"] = df["price"].pct_change()
    df.drop(index = [0], columns="price", inplace = True)
    df = df.iloc[-751:-1]
```

Now, this works properly except for the final line in the for loop. Instead of overwriting the original data frame for A, B, and C, it only modifies the dataframe currently under the label df; this shows in the variable list, where df is the only data frame with 750 rows, all the others have what they originally had minus the one dropped. Any idea on how to fix this?

On a similar note, I've got a question about memory usage. For things like this, say I want to run regressions or do some analysis of the data, which would be better, keeping each product in a separate data frame, or merging them into one big data frame? And does panda have regression-style functionalities, or would it be better to use some other library, like numpy?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to put your dataframe into a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

products= {'A':A, 'B':B, 'C':C}

for k, v in products.items():
    products[k]["change"] = products[k]["price"].pct_change()
    products[k].drop(index = [0], columns="price", inplace = True)
    products[k] = products[k].iloc[-751:-1]
```

hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the apply function which works better than any loops

```
def youfunction(args):
    return something
```

products= [A, B, C]

```
for df in products:
    df["change"] = df["price"].apply(yourfunction)
```

Note the lambda expression won't work here.